# use a button on userform to get a variable and continue with sub

Tags: vba, excel, dictionary

I have a userform in excel where a combobox compiles a dropdown using a range from another sheet.  I've defined the dropdown using a dictionary from the range and forced the combobox to match (this is done to ensure the user tries to find the company prior to adding a new one).  I do however, want them to be able to add new companies to the list if absolutely needed, thus have a button labeled "add company," and now need it to add the company they input into the list/dictionary, any ideas?

I would like to avoid having to launch a whole new userform, optimally I thought of an input box on_click of the button, but I am not sure how to force that variable back into the original userform.

My current code is:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Dim Acctsht As Worksheet
    Dim ValSet
    Dim FinanInst
    Dim objFinanInst As Object
    Dim objAcctType As Object
    Dim objNickname As Object
    Dim objFourDig As Object
    Dim objAcctClass As Object
    Dim objDescript As Object
    Dim CompanyDict As New Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim Tempsht As Worksheet
    Dim NewCompTemp As String

    Set Acctsht = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Accounts")

    With Acctsht.Range("b2:b" & Range("b:b").SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row)
        ValSet = .Value
    End With

    With CompanyDict
            .comparemode = 1
        For Each FinanInst In ValSet
            If Not .exists(FinanInst) Then .Add FinanInst, Nothing
        Next
        If .Count Then CBoxFinanInst.List = Application.Transpose(.keys)
    End With

    With CboxAcctType
        .AddItem "Checking Account"
        .AddItem "Fixed Loan"
        .AddItem "Investment Account"
        .AddItem "Money Market Account"
        .AddItem "Revolving Credit"
        .AddItem "Savings Account"

    End With

    With CBoxAcctClass
        .AddItem "Asset"
        .AddItem "Liability"

    End With

End Sub

Private Sub CButtonAddCompany_Click()

    Dim NewCompTemp As String

    Unload FrmCreateAccount

    NewCompTemp = InputBox("Please enter new company exactly as you wish it to appear", Title:="Create New Company")
    FrmCreateAccount.Show (NewCompTemp)

    Exit Sub

End Sub
```

In response to Jean-Pierre's comment below, I've tried the following code, but it's still not working:

Private Sub CButtonAddCompany_Click()

```
Dim NewCompTemp As String
Dim Acctsht As Worksheet
Dim CompanyDict As New Scripting.Dictionary

Set Acctsht = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Accounts")

NewCompTemp = InputBox("Please enter new company exactly as you wish it to appear", Title:="Create New Company")

With Acctsht.Range("b2:b" & Range("b:b").SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row)
    ValSet = .Value
End With

With CompanyDict
        .comparemode = 1
    For Each FinanInst In ValSet
        If Not .exists(FinanInst) Then .Add FinanInst, Nothing
    Next
    If .Count Then CBoxFinanInst.List = Application.Transpose(.keys)
End With

With CompanyDict
    .Add CompanyDict.Count + 1, NewCompTemp
End With

Exit Sub
```

End Sub

Only the original dropdown list in the combobox appears, regardless of what is entered and stored as NewCompTemp.

I got it, thanks to Jean-Pierre for sending me in the right direction!  I didn't realize I could run the subroutine and have it reset the dictionary right on the form.

Essentially, the dictionary was set from the initialize action, however, I didn't realize I could retrigger a set-up of the same dictionary on a button_click action.  Once I did that and ended that sub it returned to the original userform sub and voila.  Thank you for all that helped and thank you for your patience.  (older biologist here learning new skills).

Comment: Hi there and welcome to StackOverFlow, have you tried to add your `With CompanyDict....` code into the `CButtonAddCompany....` sub. Should work if you just put the code in place of the `FrmCreateAccount.Show (NewCompTemp)` youwill need to include the section where you set the `Acctsht.Range` aswell.

Comment: Hi Jean-Pierre,  Thank you for the answer!  Sorry to be obtuse, but I'm not completely proficient with VBA yet and am learning as I go...would you be able explain a bit more?  I am still unsure how to get the new variable (NewCompTemp) added to the dictionary and passed back to the form combobox.

Comment: @JMB if you found an answer to your own inquiry please feel free to post it as an answer for anyone in the future looking for a solution to a similar issue. Regards